# django admin add error to form field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following code:

Model:

```
 class MyUser(AbstractUser):
        profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

My profile model contains only some personal fields like full_name, gender, birthdate, etc.
```

Admin:

```
class MyUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MyUser
    fieldsets = .....

    filter_horizontal = ....


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = MyUser

    def clean_password(self):
        return ""


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    inlines = (MyUserInline,)
    change_user_password_template = None
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not Profile.objects.filter(myuser__username=obj.myuser.email).exclude(pk=obj.id).exists():
            obj.myuser.username = obj.myuser.email
            obj.save()
        else:
            # *MY PROBLEM IS HERE!*
```

What I am going to do is to delete username field from admin change user page and set their email as their username as well. In `AbstractUser` email is not unique but username is. The problem is when changing a user email, if email is duplicated it would raise exception, but I want to show error to say this email is duplicated. Is the only way to do that changing my `MyUser` model and add email as a unique field or I can do something else?

tnx

Comment: You want to change whole user data inside admin?

Comment: the whole `profile` fields and some `myUser` fields like email and password.